# Ionic File Transfer Plugin not working in production version

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic3

I am facing weired issue in ionic3 application.

Let me describe my situation in detail:
Actually I need offline support for my ionic app. so everytime I call the API, I store the data into local storage. and also download image from the api to my local directory. so that I can fetch data and image when internet is not available from local resources.

I am using this plugin to download image from server to local:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

It is working fine if I run following command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

But it is not working when I run following command:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

Code :

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) { }

const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

download() {
  const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```

I am not getting any error or issue from console. So I don't know what i am missing. There is also permission for local storage configured well. so permission is not an issue.

Comment: How you're telling it is not working?

Comment: @Sampath It is not showing any error nor starting download.

Comment: @HiteshUpadhyay sorry, I can't find any solution, but probably we can use something like pro-guard for prevent from obfuscating production codes.

Comment: @HiteshUpadhyay Also I open issue for this [Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1925)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I find solution for this issue! 
at the first you should update this commands:

```
npm i @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save
npm i ionic-native@latest --save
```

And probably somewhere in your code you call anything related to file-transfer plugin before

`platform.ready.then()`

In my case: I inject some service that include a line like this :

`this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();`

And I changed it to this :

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
});
```

Now everything work fine.

**More Details :**

Why this work in debug mode?

the answer is very clear, because in debug mode device ready event give a long time for fire and file-transfer called after this absolutely! But in production mode, device ready fired very fast and file-transfer called before this. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you very very much, it helped me a lot :)